# Problem with Marshal.PtrToStringAuto after calling WNetGetUniversalName

Tags: c#, marshalling

Below is my function for getting universal paths. It has been through many iterations as I find various conflicting posts on the subject, but this function works - usually.  However about 5% of the time it causes a crash of the application.  The error message indicates that it is possibly corrupted memory.  I can find no reason for that.  The problem never happens when running the c# application under the debugger, but if I attach to the process after the error then I can view the data returned by WNetGetUniversalName, and it looks exactly the same as when there is no crash. I need some ideas of what might be causing this.

```
        public static string GetUncPath (string localPath)
    {
        if (localPath.IndexOf ('\\')== 0)
            return localPath;               // already a unc path

        int bufferSize = 8000;
        IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal (bufferSize);

        int ret = WNetGetUniversalName (localPath, UNIVERSAL_NAME_INFO_LEVEL, buffer, ref bufferSize);

        if (ret == 2250)
            return localPath;

        string result = "";
        if (ret == 0) {
            IntPtr ptr = Marshal.ReadIntPtr (buffer);
            result = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto (ptr, bufferSize);
            result = result.Substring (0, result.IndexOf ('\0'));
        }
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal (buffer);
        return result;
    }

    [DllImport ("mpr.dll", EntryPoint="WNetGetUniversalName", 
       CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError=false)]
    [return: MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.U4)]
    static extern int WNetGetUniversalName (string lpLocalPath,
        [MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.U4)] int dwInfoLevel,
        IntPtr lpBuffer,
        [MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.U4)] ref int lpBufferSize);
```

The crash always happens in the call to Marshal.PtrToStringAuto.  Again, the data in the buffer looks absolutely correct when the crash has happened.

Notice that I have set up a buffer of 8000 bytes.  I started with 2000, thinking that would be plenty since the strings being returned are all less that 200 bytes.  But using 8000 seems to result in fewer crashes.  This is somewhat subjective since the crashes are totally random, sometimes not occurring for a long time and other times happening nearly every time the application is started.

This is a 64 bit application. The errors happen with Windows 7 Pro and with Windows 10.

Any Ideas?
Thanks, Russ

Ok, thanks to Ben I have the answer.  Here is my final working code:

```
public static string GetUncPath (string localPath)
{
    if (localPath.IndexOf ('\\')== 0)
        return localPath;               // already a unc path

    int bufferSize = 512;
    IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem (bufferSize);
    int ret = WNetGetUniversalName (localPath, UNIVERSAL_NAME_INFO_LEVEL, 
              buffer, ref bufferSize);

    if (ret == 2250) {            // if localpath is on the local computer
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem (buffer);
        return localPath;
    }

    string result = "";
    if (ret == 0) {
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.ReadIntPtr (buffer);
        result = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto (ptr);
    }
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem (buffer);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I note that you're not handling the case where the buffer isn't long enough and ERROR_MORE_DATA is returned. Have a look here for an implementation that fixes it: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/WNetGetUniversalName.html

Comment: The issue has to do with the type of encoding in the string. PtrToStringAuto tried to automatically detect the encoding in the string.  Does the string characters change (UTF-8 and/or Unicode)?.  If the string is always 8 bits then use UTF-8 (LpStr).  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-strings

Comment: As well as checking ERROR_MORE_DATA, my understanding from the docs is that the buffer is filled with UNIVERSAL_NAME_INFO (IntPtr size) and _then_ the actual characters, and that bufferSize will be the sum of these sizes (actual amount written to the buffer),  thus is _seems_ you should be pulling _less_ than bufferSize bytes into Marshal.PtrToStringAuto.  I would try the overload of Marshal.PtrToStringAuto that does not take a length

Comment: Not the cause of your problem, but lose the `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` and `Marshal.FreeHGlobal` and just temporarily pin an ordinary C# array.  Manual memory-management is always a mess, manual memory-management with functions which do not do what their names say is about as bad as it gets.

Comment: @jdweng: "`PtrToStringAuto` tried to automatically detect the encoding in the string" contradicts the documentation.  Where did you get that idea?

Comment: @Ben Voight : Did you look at my link?  Where is the contradictions?

Comment: @jdweng: That page doesn't even mention `PtrToStringAuto`. The [doc page for `PtrToStringAuto`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostringauto) definitively says that whether it treats the input as ANSI or Unicode depends on the platform.  There is no mention of inspecting the data to try to auto-detect, and doing so would contradict the documented platform dependence. "If the current platform is Unicode, each ANSI character is widened to a Unicode character and this method calls PtrToStringUni. Otherwise, this method calls PtrToStringAnsi."

Comment: You link has SEE ALSO which says : Copies the contents of a managed String into unmanaged memory, converting into ANSI format if required".  So doesn't "If Required" implies the default is unicode but will also handle ANSI?  See : "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobalauto?view=netcore-3.1#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_StringToHGlobalAuto_System_String_"

Comment: @jdweng: Apply some critical thinking here.  (1) That see also is to the documentation for a DIFFERENT function and does not tell you anything about how `PtrToStringAuto` works.  (2) `StringToHGlobalAuto` copies in the other direction, from managed `System.String` to an unmanaged buffer.  You are suggesting that it should detect whether its own output is ANSI or Unicode by looking at what?  The output hasn't been determined yet, there is nothing to look at for detection.  No, "If Required" cannot mean auto-detection.

Comment: Ben Voight : What does "If Required" means?

Comment: @jdweng The documentation seems to be out of date - according to [the source code](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/marshal.cs), `StringToHGlobalAuto()` doesn't even support ANSI any more.

Comment: You are looking at core 4.6.  Here us 4,8 : https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/marshal.cs,dbe8e7a6cccd5d7a  Be careful of what Microsoft tries to do and what is really needed.  I had lot of issues updating from VS 10 to VS 13 years ago. VS 13 attempted so remove all UTF-8 encoding and tried to go completely to Unicode. I had a working project that took me a few days to find a way to get VS 13 to work with 8 byte characters.  It made absolutely no sense to eliminate 8 bit characters.  So I do not believe the notes in the source code to eliminate ANSI.

Comment: Matthew, Thanks for your comment.  With a buffer of 8000 bytes I am reasonably certain that the return data will never exceed buffersize.  And I do handle the case where ERROR_MORE_DATA might be returned, by the line that says if (ret == 0).  The link you pointed me to is where I got the original code, although there were some errors on that page (which the author admitted was untested).  But by searching other postings I was able to make it work.  For my case testing for length is an unwanted distraction to getting it to work.  If the bug can be found then I may go back and add that feature.

Comment: tolan, Thanks,  I think you are correct, but I have already tried that and it did not cure the crash. My prior code line was:
result = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto (ptr, bufferSize - IntPtr.Size);

Comment: To all, I realized I should tell you that I am using VS17, SDK version 10.0.17762.0

Comment: @Ben Voight:
Thank you. But I do not understand. My understanding is that the HGlobal memory is needed because the function i am calling cannot use memory in my application's space. Is this not true?

Comment: @RussK2txb: C# `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` has nothing to do with HGLOBAL or global memory.  The name is horrible.

Comment: @Ben Voight: Ok Ben, I changed to using  Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem, which seems to do the same thing, and it works as before.
  However my crash error has gone away.  That happened before I switched to CoTaskMem though.  I was experimenting with buffer size.  I made it only 50 bytes, which caused WNetGetUniversalName to fail every time.  I then ran through around 1000 iterations to see if the crash bug would recur.  It did not.  But when I returned buffersize to normal the crash no longer happened.  I swear that I did nothing else!

Comment: @Ben Voight:  Now my buffersize is 512 bytes and the program has gone through many thousands of iterations with no failure at all.  I Hate it when a bug stops happening for no reason.  I am afraid it will come back to haunt me some day.
  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you ever change your code to account for tolanj's correct comment that the out parameter `bufferSize` is set to the total number of bytes stored in the buffer and NOT the length of the string?

Comment: Yes, you can easily bump the program in a memory layout that won't cause this crash.  Such are the joys of undefined behavior.  Just use the PtrToStringAuto(IntPtr) overload, these strings are properly zero-terminated.  The comments about letting it tell you how much space is required are correct.

Comment: @Ben Voight: From Microsoft documentation:
"If the current platform is Unicode, each ANSI character is widened to a Unicode character and this method calls PtrToStringUni. Otherwise, this method calls PtrToStringAnsi.", So I don't see the problem with calling Auto.

However, I think you have identified the problem with your comment about the second parameter.  I can hardly believe I did not see it myself.  I took that code from an example but did not notice that I did not need the second parameter.  I removed it and the line below and now all seems well.  Thank You!

Comment: @RussK2txb: You are using the version with two parameters, pointer and size, which says "On Unicode platforms, this method calls `PtrToStringUni`; on ANSI platforms, it calls `PtrToStringAnsi`. **No transformations are done before these methods are called.**"

Answer (score 1):

There are three errors in the following line:

```
result = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto (ptr, bufferSize);
```

One was pointed out in the comments by @tolanj -- on return `bufferSize` is the total number of bytes written, including the size of the `_UNIVERSAL_NAME_INFOW` structure itself.  Not the number of bytes in the string.

Second is that `Marshal.PtrToStringAuto`'s second argument is the number of **characters** to read from the specified pointer, but you are passing the number of **bytes**.

Third is that you imported the function with `CharSet.Unicode`, so you know you are always getting `WNetGetUniversalNameW`, `_UNIVERSAL_NAME_INFOW`, and UTF-16 string data.  So you should use `PtrToStringUni` not `PtrToStringAuto`<sup>1</sup>.  Both the above concerns also apply to `PtrToStringUni`.

---

`PtrToStringAuto` behavior is documented as

> On Unicode platforms, this method calls `PtrToStringUni`; on ANSI platforms, it calls `PtrToStringAnsi`. No transformations are done before these methods are called.

You don't want sometimes one, sometimes the other.  The p/invoke declaration is forcing Unicode on all platforms.